# Send an array with ajax request to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a js function GetTableData() that gets an array like this. [rowindex,[value1,value2,value3...]]. I want to send over these array using Ajax POST to a php script or url. This time, its not variables that are being sent over but its a function GetTableData() that holds the array of values. How do I go about this as no data is being sent.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();                      
    vars = function GetTableData;// This is my problem
    hr.open("POST", "destination.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.table_attendance == 200) {
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("resultsdiv").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

HTML code here

```
<input type="button" value="Post using Ajax" onClick="javascript:ajax_post() );" />
```

Comment: You're trying to send the actual function, which is impossible. You need to send the RESULTS of that function, e.g. `vars = GetTableData()`

Comment: Ok. Marc. i'm checking it out

Comment: what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc B also points out:

```
var vars = GetTableData();
```

This will only work if GetTableData is defined in a higher scope than the current function and is accessible to that function.

Also make sure GetTableData "returns" the data; so your function:

```
function GetTableData()
{
    return [rowindex,[value1,value2,value3..]];
}
```

Comment: Ok..function GetTableData() is in an included js file in a directory . /scripts/js/file.js

Answer (score 0):

Besides you have to call your `GetTableData` as `vars = GetTableData();`, you have to encode your request data:

```
hr.send("tableData=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(vars)));
```

We do 2 encodings

- `encodeURIComponent` Mandatory, required to be sent by POST with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `JSON.stringify` Optional (can be another encoding method). Has to be an encoding method that your backend cand decode. JSON is a great one and almost a standard

Then, parse it (decode) in the backend. For example in PHP

```
$tableData = json_decode($_POST['tableData'])
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: destination.php seems not to get any data. any ideas?